# how to create MPI custom type properly

Tags: c, types, segmentation-fault, mpi

I have structure(single element of complex matrix):

```
typedef struct  s_complex_number {
    int real;
    int img;
}               ComplexNumber;
```

This is how i described Complex matrix as custom MPI datatype

```
#define SIZE_COL 10
MPI_Datatype  matrix;
MPI_Datatype  types[2] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT};
MPI_Datatype  row;
MPI_Datatype  complexNumber;
MPI_Aint      disp[2];
ComplexNumber ***recvData;
ComplexNumber ***sendData;
ComplexNumber example;

int blockLength[] = {1, 1};

disp[0] = (uintptr_t)&example.real - (uintptr_t)&example;
disp[1] = (uintptr_t)&example.img - (uintptr_t)&example;

/***********************Initialize custom types************************/
MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blockLength, disp, types, &complexNumber);
MPI_Type_commit(&complexNumber);

MPI_Type_vector(1, SIZE_COL, 1, complexNumber, &row);
MPI_Type_commit(&row);

MPI_Type_vector(1, SIZE_COL, 1, row, &matrix);
MPI_Type_commit(&matrix);
/**********************************************************************/
```

Each time i am trying to send data, geting segmentation fault.

How to describe ComplexNumber** type in MPI properly?

Comment: you can use the predefined `MPI_2INT` datatype. MPI expects data in contiguous memory (e.g. no jagged array) and it is up to you to ensure that.

Answer (score 0):

Sending/receiving `ComplexNumber ***mat` with MPI is very cumbersome. You need to create a structure datatype with as many fields as there are rows in `mat`, then set the offset of each of them to be the absolute address of the beginning of the corresponding row, and finally use `MPI_BOTTOM` as the buffer address in the send/receive call:

```
MPI_Datatype theMatrix;
MPI_Datatype types[SIZE_COL];
MPI_Aint disps[SIZE_COL];
int blocklengts[SIZE_COL];

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_COL; i++)
{
   types[i] = row;
   disps[i] = (MPI_Aint) (*mat)[i];
   blocklents[i] = 1;     
}

MPI_Type_create_struct(SIZE_COL, blocklengths, disps, types, &theMatrix);
MPI_Type_commit(&theMatrix);

MPI_Send(MPI_BOTTOM, 1, theMatrix, ...);

MPI_Type_free(&theMatrix);
```

Things to note:

- `theMatrix` can be used to send `mat` and only `mat` - no other pointer to an array of pointers object is likely to have each row at the same address in memory. Which is why `theMatrix` is freed right after the call to `MPI_Send`, because it's useless, unless the matrix space will be reused and sent again and again.
- The offsets of the structure fields are the addresses of the rows. It is possible to use `(char *)(*mat)[i] - (char *)mat`, but that's even more cumbersome.
- Since the offsets are absolute addresses, `MPI_BOTTOM` is specified as the buffer address. That is essentially `0` -- the bottom of the address space. If `(char *)(*mat)[i] - (char *)mat` was used instead for the offsets, then you have to provide `mat` instead of `MPI_BOTTOM`.

On the other hand, sending/receiving a flat matrix, i.e.,

```
ComplexNumber *mat = malloc(SIZE_COL * SIZE_COL * sizeof(ComplexNumber));
```

boils down to:

```
MPI_Send(mat, 1, matrix, ...);
```

That's the memory layout the datatype created following your code describes.